# Protractor: how to click menu element from dropdown list menu

Tags: angularjs, testing, drop-down-menu, protractor, end-to-end

I have dropdown menu like this:

```
PROJECTS v
         View Projects
         Add Project
```

I want protractor to click "Add Project" element. To do this user has to click down arrow (v character) first to show 2 sub elemnts (View Projects, Add Project).

The is the code:

```
<div class="dropdown btn-group open" ng-show="canAccessProjects">
   <button class="dropdown-toggle btn navbar-btn btn-success" ng-class="{'btn navbar-btn btn-success': isActive('/project'), 'btn navbar-btn btn-info': !isActive('/project')}" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li role="presentation"><div class="dropdown-option ng-binding" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" ng-click="menuButtonClicked('/project')">View Projects</div></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li role="presentation"><div class="dropdown-option ng-binding" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" ng-click="menuButtonClicked('/project/add/step0')">**Add Project**</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

1. Can protractor click on the "Add Project" link before clicking white arrow? (user can't)
2. How to click this element (Add Project) - div nas no ID, only differs by CSS - should I do that by

   ```
   element(by.css('.menuButtonClicked('/project/add/step0')'))
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`protractor` cannot click an invisible element - as a real user cannot. "Add Project" can be found either by text, or by index, or relying on the `ng-click`.

Let's, for the sake of an example, use `by.xpath`. Here I'm finding the arrow button, clicking it and getting the following `ul` sibling, then using `last()` to get the last `li` in the list:

```
var button = element(by.id('dropdownMenu1'));
button.click();

button.element(by.xpath('following-sibling::ul/li[last()]/div')).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it in the e2e test for the protractor website:

```
// Page object
$('.dropdown.open')
   .element(by.linkText(itemName))
   .click();

// And this is how it looks like in the test:
var menu = require('./menu-partial');
menu.dropdown('Protractor Setup').item('Setting Up the Browser')
```

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/website/test/e2e/menu-partial.js#L43

Comment: Nice, you made a page object out of the menu items!